# How can i capture screen region while not focusing wpf app?

Tags: wpf, background-process, capture

I have a WPf application that monitors a certain region on screen keeping track of the count of pixels with certain colors.

What i want is the actual capturing of the region and reading of values to happen in another thread, but i cant seem to wrap my head around how to actuale grab the region while i focus another window.

Here is some code:

```
// Colors to keep track of
var fooColor = (System.Windows.Media.Color)System.Windows.Media.ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FF6ebfe2");
var barColor = (System.Windows.Media.Color)System.Windows.Media.ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FFe67e6e");

// previewWindow : Rectangle Control
var X = (int)previewWindow.PointToScreen(new System.Windows.Point(0, 0)).X;
var Y = (int)previewWindow.PointToScreen(new System.Windows.Point(0, 0)).Y;
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(X, Y, (int)previewWindow.ActualWidth, (int)previewWindow.ActualHeight);
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
using (var screenBmp = new Bitmap(
    rect.Width,
    rect.Height,
    System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
)
{
    using (var bmpGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(screenBmp))
    {
        bmpGraphics.CopyFromScreen(X, Y, 0, 0, screenBmp.Size);
        BitmapSource bmpSource = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
            screenBmp.GetHbitmap(),
            IntPtr.Zero,
            Int32Rect.Empty,
            BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
        var red = 0;
        var blue = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < rect.Width; i++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < rect.Height; x++)
            {
                System.Windows.Media.Color color = GetPixelColor(bmpSource, i, x);
                if (color == fooColor)
                {
                    blue++;
                }
                else if (color == barColor)
                {
                    red++;
                }
            }
        }
        txtbar.Text = red.ToString();
        txtfoo.Text = blue.ToString();
        if (red < 150)
        {
            ProcessBar();
        }
        if (blue < 150)
        {
            ProcessFoo();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Here is some code` - is this yours or someone else's and you don't know where or how to invoke it? - because it doesn't seem to contain any focus-related logic.

Comment: I have written it. What i want is to capture the region of screen where that rectangle is. What i have is a window with adjustable width and height, and a button click event. I have tried to run this in a background thread in a while (true) loop with a thread.sleep but as soon as the wpf application loses focus the capturing does not work.